# error 0xc000007b while launching the unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I went on unity this morning and I got an error while launching the editor[image]

It says

> Unity.exe - Program Error
>
> The program didn't launched correctly (0xc000007b). Click on OK to close the program.

I've reinstalled unity and it still showed me this error. I searched on google and found nothing that worked for me. Do you guys have any solution?

Comment: Contact Unity technical support.

Comment: Find EditorLog inside Unity installation for the reason.

Comment: @MickyD they are busy so they'll answer in 2 weeks